# PySpark toLocalIterator always hangs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I havea PySpark dataframe with 49954 rows that look like this:

```
>>pp.pprint(first_row.asDict())

{'broadcast_size': DenseVector([2861334.0, 2861334.0]),
 'comment_count': DenseVector([0.0]),
 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 0, 42, 34, 246795),
 'features': SparseVector(10984, {2: 1.0, 282: 1.0, 287: 0.1847, 288: 0.9828, 289: 1.0, 10981: -0.0726}),
 'feed_id': 391,
 'label': 12,
 'onehot_weekday': SparseVector(6, {1: 1.0}),
 'publisher_id': 2,
 'std_broadcast_size': DenseVector([0.0, 0.0]),
 'vertical_id': 0,
 'wave_time': DenseVector([0.1847, 0.9828]),
 'weekday': 1}
```

I would like to use `toLocalIterator` to operate on values one row at a time, like so:

```
for row in data.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    do_stuff(row)
```

However, my spark jobs completely hang on `toLocalIterator`. It doesn't even seem to matter what is contained in the dataframe, because I have seen this issue with other datasets in my application as well.

The spark dashboard UI lists a task titled `Zeppelin toLocalIterator at <stdin>:5` while attempting the iteration as shown above, but it just runs indefinitely without any error messages. The longest I let it run was 30 minutes, out of curiosity.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you `cache()` dataframe before `toLocalIterator()`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've just tried to cache first, and I'm afraid the result is the same.